# How to get Eclipse Compiler for Java batch package 4.5.2+

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt, ecj

Version `4.5.1` is the last one available from central - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler/ecj/4.5.1

Unfortunately there is a nasty bug, which [was fixed only in `4.5.2`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=461004).

I cannot seem to find a binary package anywhere. I tried building it from sources but failed (details below). **What is the recommended way to obtain 4.5.2 binary?**

I tried https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.core but it doesn't have any relevant tags.

I tried building the tag `R4_5_2` from https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tag/?h=R4_5_2
Suprisingly it still has a snapshot version `4.5.2-SNAPSHOT` and requires a parent of the same version. I can try building the parent project, but I'd expect it to be already available in some repository etc. Before proceeding I'd like at least to know if this path is going to lead anywhere.

Finally I came across [Project Tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) but I think this is only relevant if I'm creating a new plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one here by random googling: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5.2-201602121500/#JDTCORE

However the timestamp is different than what I get in my Eclipse Mars. Here it's `20160212-1500` and in Eclipse I have `20160128-0629`

Comment: 201602121500 is the correct timestamp for the final 4.5.2 release. 201601280629 sounds like a release candidate or nightly build.

Comment: @greg-449 thats strange -- how did I get `201601280629` into my Eclipse Mars then? I only update via official update sites/marketplace